# How to upload .gif file but not working ASP MVC after upload

Tags: model-view-controller, upload, gif

```
public List<string> Upload(HttpPostedFileBase[] files) 
{
    //string size = fc["size"];
    int sizeResize = AppSettings.Company.ChieuRongToiDaCuaHinhUpload ?? 1500;
    //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(size))
    //{
    //    int.TryParse(size, out sizeResize);
    //}

    List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        // Duyệt qua các file được gởi lên phía client
        foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
        {
            //Lấy ra file trong list các file gởi lên
            //HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
            //Save file content goes here

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //Định nghĩa đường dẫn lưu file trên server
                //ở đây mình lưu tại đường dẫn yourdomain.com/Uploads/
                var originalDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(string.Format("{0}Uploads\\{1}\\", Server.MapPath(@"\"),"files"));
                //Lưu trữ hình ảnh theo từng tháng trong năm
                string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM"));

                bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString);
                if (!isExists) System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);

                var path = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", pathString, Common.Tools.StringTools.ConvertToUnSignNoneDotSign(file.FileName));
                string newFileName = file.FileName;
                //lấy đường dẫn lưu file sau khi kiểm tra tên file trên server có tồn tại hay không
                //thư mục files nằm trong CKFinder để quản lý file
                var newPath = GetNewPathForDupes(path, ref newFileName);
                string serverPath = string.Format("/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}", "Uploads","files", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM"), newFileName);

                //nếu là loại file hình thì resize, còn lại khỏi
                if(file.ContentType.Contains("image"))
                {
                    //Lưu hình ảnh Resize từ file sử dụng file.InputStream
                    SaveResizeImage(Image.FromStream(file.InputStream), sizeResize, newPath);

                    //Tạo hình Thumbnail
                    StringTools.CreateThumbnail(newFileName, pathString, withThumbnailImage, withThumbnailImage, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    file.SaveAs(newPath);
                }
                
                fileNames.Add(serverPath);
                //fileNames.Add("LocalPath: " + newPath + "<br/>ServerPath: " + serverPath);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TempData["e"] = ex.Message;
        logger.Error(ex.Message);
    }
    TempData["file"] = fileNames;

    return fileNames;

    //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    //return RedirectToAction("Edit", "VL_TinTuyenDung");

}
```

Comment: I suggest to introduce your question with a text, rather than a code. Please avoid Vietnamese caracters: there are very nice to look, but not everyone understand it and they may cause encoding issues, which are unrelated to your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include details of the error. "not working" is not enough detail for people to easily understand the problem. Also add a tag for the language you are using.